# SVG image loses quality when resized

Tags: swift, svg, uibutton, uiimageview, uikit

[image: img1]

As you can see on the image above, these two `svg` images are losing their quality a bit. In `Assets`'s Attributes inscpector, their `Scale` property is set to `Single Scale`.

Those are button's imageViews, resized to fill the button:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: img1.rawValue), for: .normal) 
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this piece of code for resizing images to the desired size without losing quality

```
extension UIImage {
    func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:targetSize).image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
        }
    }
}
```