# IOS Swift SVG image quality issues when resized

Tags: swift, image, svg, swiftui, resize-image

[resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnniD.png)

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKXfv.png)

As you can see in the image, SVG images are losing their quality when I resize them to 200X200. Isn't that against SVG images logic? I think the SVG images should not be corrupted no matter how big I enlarge it. What can I do for it? Which method can i follow?

I resized the SVG image like this in SwiftUI

```
  Image(uiImage: .flame.resize(targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)))
```

I used this piece of code to resize image. This not working. You can see in the resized image above. I found this solution here.
[Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69118833/12032861)

```
extension UIImage {
    func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:targetSize).image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "found this solution here" Well, that code is wrong for an svg. What you're getting is exactly to be expected. You are rendering to a bitmap and then resizing, thus losing all the svg advantage you were wishing for.

Comment: @matt I can't find any documentation for using this. I put it in the Asset Catalog and I'm trying to use it. Svg is said to be supported after iOS 13+. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can put an SVG into the asset catalog, but when you build, it will be turned into a bitmap. You need to make it a regular resource and then use a 3rd party lib to render — see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691839/how-to-display-svg-image-using-swift

Comment: Alternatively you could render with WebKit.

Comment: "Am I missing something?" @BetulAksu Well it appears to _me_ that you're missing _everything_. See my answer below for a counterexample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know much about SwiftUI, but here's an example of a single SVG displaying accurately at multiple sizes in UIKit image views:

[image]

That was done without code. All I did was to configure the SVG in the asset catalog to have a single size and to preserve vector data:

[image]

That is completely different from what you're doing; you are *drawing* the SVG into a graphics context, so you are throwing away the vector data and substituting a bitmap, which of course does not scale perfectly.

Comment: selecting this worked in both swiftui and uikit.

Answer (score -1):

Not pretending to give a full answer, just a few ideas:

1. Please check this [nice tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/controlling-image-interpolation-in-swiftui) which explains the need of using `.interpolation(.none)` in such cases for `SwiftUI.Image`.
2. Don't resize the UI image - resize only SwiftUI image, as now you know a very simple way to deny interpolation.
3. If the step 2 won't work (e.g. no transparency(alpha channel) or some other problems), probably you'll have to pre-process that `UIImage` with CoreGraphics (this is definitely not performant, but may look good).
4. In the worst-case scenario, you'll have to implement that `UIImage.resize` function using `CGContext`, paying attention to the interpolation quality.

So, the main ideas are:

1. You tried `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, but there still are a lot of other options to explore, and you should check them one-by-one to get some intuition of what works and what doesn't.
2. Your resized image looks blurry, so the main issue is probably with the interpolation (mixing a neighbouring pixels' alpha channel when you downscale), so you should deny the  interpolation. You can investigate how to fix the performance issues once everything is rendered well.